How to shorten my code so it can meet command jumping length
I have this code that I'm trying to run but it tells me that it's too big of a jump.
At first it said "Relative jump out of range by 0015h bytes" when the code was this:
restart:
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax
    
    mov bx, offset dir
    mov [bx], di
    mov di, 3
    mov bx, offset st_am
    mov [bx], di
    
    push offset preFrame
    push offset menu
    push offset Instructions
    push offset nowPause
    call screens
    
    call black
    
    mov di, offset app
    push di ;Give to apple apple location
    call apple
    
    mov di, offset SPL
    push di ;Give to starterSnake initial snake location
    call starterSnake
    
;Give to up/down/left/right SPL, apple & amount
    mov di, offset dir
    push di
    mov di, offset color
    push di
    mov di, offset st_am
    push di
    mov di, offset app
    push di
    mov di, offset SPL
    push di
    
wasd:
    mov ah, 1h
    int 16h
    jnz newDir ;Check if there's something in the buffer, if not continue
    
    call delay
   
    cmp [dir], 'q'
    jz exit
    cmp [dir], 'a'
    jz a
    cmp [dir], 's'
    jz s
    cmp [dir], 'd'
    jz d
    cmp [dir], 'w'
    jz w
    cmp [dir], 'r'
    jz restart

and when I changed it to:
;Give to up/down/left/right SPL, apple & amount
    push offset dir
    push offset color
    push offset st_am
    push offset app
    push offset SPL

and removed lines it said "Relative jump out of range by 0033h bytes"
which is a bigger range and it doesn't make any sense. Can someone help me?
*THE JUMP IS FROM "jz restart" !!

Depending on the assembler, you might get away with jz near restart. If that doesn't work there's always jnz skip; jmp restart; skip: --- this works since pure jmp has longer range than the conditional ones.

If you don't need to run this on old cpus you can just select a cpu which supports longer range conditional jumps (e.g. put a .386 at the top of your file).

Anyway, loading dir into al and comparing that is also 3 bytes shorter per cmp. Obviously mov di, 3; mov bx, offset st_am; mov [bx], di is just a convoluted way to write mov byte ptr [st_am], 3 as well.

@Jester Surely you meant mov word ptr [st_am], 3 ?

Thanks to @500 - Internal Server Error !!
I changed the code to this:
cmp [dir], 'r'
    jnz skip
    jmp restart
skip:

jmp has a bigger range.
